# IntelliJ IDEA 14 で、`Default` キーマップが使えなくなった

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 14 (for Mac)にアップグレードしたところ、`Preference`画面で、`Default`という`Keymap`プリセットを選択できなくなりました（選択肢に表示されません）。

Command + Shift + A > Keymap でポップアップされる一覧には`Default`が表示されますが、ここではプリセットを選択することしか出来ないので、新しいキーバインドを増やしたりできず不便です。

解決する方法はありますか？